# How to save video from my iphone 5 to Time Capsule?

Tags: time-capsule, iphone

Is it possible to save video from my iphone 5 to Time Capsule? If yes, how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Time Capsule can only backup through Time Machine. Since the iPhone doesn't run Time Machine, you can't backup the video directly.